# Pass more than one input into Map State in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-step-functions

I have an input like this:

```
{
  "object": "cmdb_ci",
  "time_window": {
    "from": "2022-11-01 00:00:00",
    "to": "2022-12-01 00:00:00"
  },
  "config": {
    "extract_type": "micro-batch",
    "interval_time_to_extract": 5,
    "key_time_based_property_to_extract": "sys_updated_on",
    "url_path": "/now/table/"
  },
  "result": [],
  "totals": 1032933,
  "list_offsets": [
    1032800,
    1032600,
    1032400,
    1032200,
    1032000,
    1031800,
    ....
    ]
}
```

And my Step Func is as follows, I am using **"offset.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"** to get each item in **list_offsets**.

```
{
  "Type": "Map",
  "MaxConcurrency": 20,
  "ItemsPath": "$.list_offsets",
  "Parameters": {
    "object.$": "$.object",
    "time_window.$": "$.time_window",
    "config.$": "$.config",
    "offset.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
  },
  "Iterator": {
    "StartAt": "Extract and Store a single page",
    "States": {
      "Extract and Store a single page": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "",
        "Retry": [...],
        "End": true
      }
    }
  },
  "Catch": [...],
  "End": true
}
```

Is there any way I can get 2 items at once ?

Input result expected for Step Func: Get 2 items in a Map

I tried using **"offset.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"** and got only 1 item per 1 Map State
My expected result is to get 2 items in one Map State